# How to properly position more than 100% width in react

Tags: css, reactjs, carousel, react-player

I am using react-responsive-carousel to create a carosouel of youtube videos as in http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/storybook/?path=/story/02-advanced--youtube-autoplay-with-custom-thumbs.

I want to remove the blackbox on the sides as shown in the image.
[image: with black sides]

I used `<ReactPlayer width="100%" url={url} playing={isSelected} height="100%" />` .

When I try `width=120%` I somewhat get the result I want. [image: with one black side]

Is there any way to get the video in the center so that to cover the full area with no black spaces on either sides.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the player by using the style.

`<ReactPlayer style={{margin:"auto",text-align:"center",width="100%"}} url={url} playing={isSelected} height="100%" />`